# show joomla component in menu item type

Tags: joomla, components

I made a component for Joomla and it's working ok with the direct url: http://www.something.com/index.php?option=com_pbform

The problem is that when I try to add it in the menu.
When I change the menu item type, the component is listed, but when I click on it I don't get a view to apply to the menu item.

Do I have to configure anything else in the component?

Thank you!

Comment: I found this line in one of tutorials. "You can also hide a view by using an underscore '_' in the name". I lose many hours before find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup your component in the MVC fashion then you would have a views/layout folder structure in your component folder. Each different view you have in there will be listed in the menu types under your component name. This is where the views can be chosen.

For e.g. in your component folder structure you have

```
views/view_a
views/view_b
views/view_c
```

then in the Joomla menu selector you would have those choices to select as a view.

If you haven't setup your component as MVC then have a look at this tutorial on how to do just that http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components

I hope that helps!
Cheers

Comment: yes, i did it in the MVC fashion, the problem is that I didn't use the jview, I did a mvc approach from scratch, and I have a folder with all the views I need. Is there any workaround that let me use this approach in the menu types?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, but my guess would be that you would need to initialise your view(s) with Joomla in your controller so it knows they are there. Check this thread (http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=511442) out, it might help you.

Comment: ok, I did it different. In menu type I choose External Link and write the component url (index.php?option=com_mycomponent&template=temp1). But thanks anyway for the tips! Your first link will be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**Add your component to jos_components table:**

```
INSERT INTO jos_components (name, link, admin_menu_link, `option`)
VALUES (
  'Greetings', 'option=com_greetings', 'option=com_greetings', 'com_greetings')
```

If you have all your views set up correctly you need to add your component into the Joomla database.

Functions and view folders must have no hyphens or underscores.

**Good**

- /view/viewone
- /view/viewtwo
- /view/viewthree

**Bad**

- /view/view_one
- /view/view_two
- /view/view_three

Answer (score 1):

You may need a metadata.xml file for each of your views. See http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_view_layout_configuration_parameters for more details

Comment: I try that, but the problem is I have my own view classes. I don't use joomla view classes. I have also a slightly different way of organizing the component folders. Maybe I have also to include something inside the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple solution. You expected to find your new component in the menu item type drop-down list, but its not there! Instead of trying to cope with that ugly MVC scrap do this:

- select  "single article"  from the list and SAVE your new menu item
- now open your joomla db
- select _menu table
- edit your menu row
- change link from article to index.php?option=com_yourcomponent
- save and take a look at administrator menu manager

I did migrate my `Joomla 1.5` collection of  Ajax/PHP scripts to `Joomla 1.7.3` using this solution in just one day.

Piece of cake.