# Updating MySQL table from callback URL in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, callback, joomla2.5, payment-gateway

My website is built on joomla 2.5.8. the website is using payment gateway for processing payments.

As you know joomla has this structure for URLs (without SEF):

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&controller=order&task=notify&gateway=paymentgateway
```

Now, the payment gateway provider asked me to send them a callback URL to pass the values of the transaction into it and to let me update MySQL database table with the transaction info based on this URL values.

The problem is that the payment gateway provider will use these values in the callback URL:

```
?Response=1&status=10&code=123456-123456&token=f0021bfa-7ae4-48af-b4a2-d08d7a647b5e&lang=en&ignore=1
```

And the link that my component use as callback URL should be this:

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&controller=order&task=notify&gateway=paymentgateway
```

Therefore the payment provider refused to setup this callback URL in their system as it contains "?" in it. And they have to use this "?" to pass the transaction values within the callback URL.

So if they accept the callback I gave them, the callback URL will look like this:

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&controller=order&task=notify&gateway=paymentgateway?Response=1&status=10&code=123456-123456&token=f0021bfa-7ae4-48af-b4a2-d08d7a647b5e&lang=en&ignore=1
```

as you noticed above the callback URL will holds two "?" question marks.

What I did so far:
I have a component installed that can SEF any non-SEF URLs in my Joomla website. So I SEF this link (index.php?option=com_componentname&controller=order&task=notify&gateway=paymentgateway) to be (payment-status) and I send it back to the payment provider. However, the passed values in the callback URL doesn't update my database table.

So everything is ok during the payment process. And once I reached the point to get the parameters' values to update my database it doesn't. How can I solve this issue out?

BR,

Comment: Please stop using flags to get attention for your question. These are only visible to site moderators and are not to be used to ask for help or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a menu item to your component so you can make a menu item for the callback page. Then you can use the built in Joomla SEF URL as the callback URL. Since it is a menu item, it will pass the correct parameters needed along with the additional values your payment processor sends back.

If you are not familiar with menu items for a component you can look here - [show joomla component in menu item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092723/show-joomla-component-in-menu-item-type)

Comment: I'm trying the last trick mentioned on the link you provided and feed you back.

Comment: What I did: I create a menu item pointing to single article and name it payment-status and alias payment-status too. Then went to phpmyadmin and amend the link there to point to this "index.php?option=com_componentname&controller=order&task=notify&gateway=paymentgateway". then I tried a test payment and still this link doesn't updating my DB.

Comment: Any idea of what I might done wrong and/or what is the solution for this?

Comment: It sounds like one of the parameters is not being passed to the page. The place to start would be to dump all the parameter values on the screen so you can see what is and is not being successfully passed to the page.